# run a WebJob from Asp.Net MVC azure website

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

What I want to do is run WebJob from my Asp.Net MVC azure website periodically without having to go through https://portal.azure.com/

Can I get the rest calls using Azure Resource Explorer for Azure Webjobs so that I can run it?  I looked but I don't see the one I created

Comment: One thing you didn't specify is whether the WebJobs are hosted in the same Web App as your MVC app, or some arbitrary other Web App. The difference might affect authentication.

Answer (score 3):

Resource Explorer doesn't currently show this, but I can give you the API here. To invoke a triggered WebJob, do a POST like this (with empty request body):

```
POST /subscriptions/{sub}/resourceGroups/{rg}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{site}/triggeredwebjobs/{jobname}/run?api-version=2015-08-01
```

There is also a way to do it via the Kudu API instead of going through ARM, and is documented [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#invoke-a-triggered-job).

The difference between the two is how you authenticate, in the first case using ARM token, and in the second case using basic auth publishing credentials. But they both do the same in the end.

Answer (score 0):

- If it periodically, you can schedule your webjob in the azure portal or using setting deployment ([Deploy WebJobs using Visual Studio](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/#publishsettings)):

> When you configure a Console Application for WebJobs deployment, Visual Studio installs the Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish NuGet package and stores scheduling information in a webjob-publish-settings.json file in the project Properties folder of the WebJobs project. Here is an example of that file:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "WebJob1",
  "startTime": "2014-06-23T00:00:00-08:00",
  "endTime": "2014-06-27T00:00:00-08:00",
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Minute",
  "interval": 5,
  "runMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

- Another option `TimerTriggerAttribute` : using the latest WebJobs SDK, which supports triggering job functions on schedule, based on the same CRON expression format. You can use it to schedule your job :

  ```
  public static void TimerJob([TimerTrigger("00:01:00")] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
  {
      log.WriteLine("Scheduled job fired!");
  }
  ```
- Other option : use the [Webjob API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API):

  ```
  Invoke a triggered job**
  POST /api/triggeredwebjobs/{job name}/run
  ```
- Last option: use the [Azure Management Libraries from Azure Web Jobs](http://blog.lytzen.name/2015/07/using-azure-management-libraries-from.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Kudu Api...  Here is a rough example...

```
ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] data = encoder.GetBytes(serializedObjHere);

var url = "https://{site}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/{jobname}/run";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("{username}", "{password}"); //you can get these in yoru publish profile
request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
request.Method = "POST";
request.Timeout = 60000; //60 seconds
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
response.Dispose();
```